# tomcat request servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How do I map a url to a HttpServlet class in tomcat.

Example I want requests /calc to be handled by Calc.java

so a request to `127.0.0.1:800/calc` would call:

```
public class Calc extends HttpServlet {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on tomcat7 it's as easy as adding the annotation:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/calc")
public class Calc extends HttpServlet {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this configuration should be in `web.xml` in your `war` file, not in tomcat.

If you are using Servlet3.0 then you may use annotations also.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/yoururl")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit greatly from reading [the Tomcat manual section on "your first webapp"](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html), which covers this.

Answer (score 0):

Add following configuration in your web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>calcServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>packagename.Calc</servlet-class> <!-- change the name of package according to your class -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>calcServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/calc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```